# How to add js in head of wordpress without using theme files or plugins

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a javascript file into Wordpress but i don't want to use a plugin or any theme file like functions.php
How can i do that?

I have already tried using a plugin as well as functions.php, but my client don't want to use either of these.

Comment: It is possible to directly insert javascript in header.php or footer.php?

Comment: Did you client explain *why* they don't want to use these methods? If JS is included in the 'normal' manner, WordPress will handle dependancies and conflicts automatically. I'm curious as to why they'd *not* want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your theme folder conman file like header, footer etc...

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/foldername/yourfilename.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

put this line before  tag in footer.php
Here I am using bootstrap JS. you have to first put bootstrap.js in JS folder of your theme